# ListVIew is not a sliding drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Hi guys i'm new to android and i'm in a learning phase. I followed tutorial on Navigation drawer from [androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) and made that code backward compatible for 2.3.3.
but i'm getting error as follows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.assignment.drawersam/com.assignment.drawersam.MainDrawerActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View android.widget.ListView{4170e148 VFED.VC. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f05003e app:id/list_slidermenu} is not a sliding drawer
```

I'm not able to understand what the error is and how to rectify it.
any help would be appreciated.

code in onCreate():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_drawer);

mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
// load slide menu items
navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItem = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItem.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItem.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItem);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }
```

code in activity_main_drawer.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainDrawerActivity" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#369"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46168568/3496570

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html), DrawerLayout must be the root view of the layout.

Remove the LinearLayout and let the DrawerLayout be the root view.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on a version compatible with earlier versions of android (Api level 7 and above) you need android support library v7 also to make it work. Here's the complete code: [Sliding menu based on androidhive code for api level 7 and above](https://github.com/GreenApplee/SlidingMenu-Android)

Comment: Hey I really appreciated your response. Yes I have included v7 support library.