# Error : View android.widget.ListView is not a sliding drawer

Tags: android

I am using `NavigationDrawer` in my Android app, I have made my own custom layouts XML file and their adapters also but When I run my program then my application crash with below logs , I could not trace the reason why it so, Any suggestion ?

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slider_menu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;

    // NavDrawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // App title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons
        navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_slider_menu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));


        // recyle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                displayView(position);
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Crash Logs :

```
03-30 08:08:35.538    3615-3615/com.example.navigationdrawerdemo.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.navigationdrawerdemo.app/com.example.navigationdrawerdemo.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View android.widget.ListView{52755e48 VFED.VC. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f08003e app:id/list_slider_menu} is not a sliding drawer
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View android.widget.ListView{52755e48 VFED.VC. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f08003e app:id/list_slider_menu} is not a sliding drawer
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1059)
            at com.example.navigationdrawerdemo.app.MainActivity.displayView(MainActivity.java:124)
            at com.example.navigationdrawerdemo.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:83)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your `ListView` must specify the `android:layout_gravity` attribute in the xml so it can be identified as sliding drawer by the DrawerLayout.
Use right, left, start, end as values.

Comment: Can you explain a bit what this attribute does If I set it to "right" and If I to "left" and "end" ?

Comment: It determines where your sliding drawer is going to show up, right and left are clear.
Start and end are used in case of language change.
If set to start for example, for right to left languages it will appear from right, and left to right languages it will appear from the left.

Comment: I did not get what exactly right and left for ??. I am confused with your term "for right to left language" and "for left to right languages", what are they ??

Comment: This menu shows at a certain side of the screen .. either right or left.
But you may want this side to be determined based on the app language.
English is a left to right language your write from left to right .. Arabic on the other hand is a right to left language.
So the option start will make the menu show at the left side if the language is english and on the right if the language is arabic, for example.
I've not actually tried the start and end options but that's what it says in the docs.

Comment: my listview does not contain `android:gravity` attribute. What wrong I may be doign?

Comment: I provided `android:layout_gravity="start"` and it worked. And still can't understand why.

Comment: @Darpan , you simply have to specify from where your drawer is going to show, android can't show it if you didn't provide gravity for it.

Comment: I tried assigning gravity to it, But my eclipse was not showing it in suggestions. So I manually wrote it and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem with tutorial of Android Hive. But after I found one magical solution.

Put `android:layout_gravity="start"` or `android:layout_gravity="left"` in your `ListView`

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listSlideMenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left" 
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="@color/color_primary"/>
```

I got the same issue learn from androidhive perfectly working with gravity="start" but on gravity change to end it raise error

Answer (score 0):

> While using `DrawerLayout` make sure it is the **rootLayout**. don't make it a child of `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

as closeDrawer come up with two override function first View and second Gravity

As normally it is close by Gravity. So in order to close drawer you must set

```
android:layout_gravity =""
```

> and all android:layout_gravity must be unique in DrawerLayout

```
 drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)//this code close the drawer child with layout_gravity ="start".
```

and if you have some other view like **linearLayout above listView** give `layout_gravity` to that `layout` and remove it from listView. drawer close item on the basis of gravity

```
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ///drawer.closeDrawer(anyViewToClose);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);//but it is better to do this using gravity.
```

See closeDrawer code

```
public void closeDrawer(@EdgeGravity int gravity, boolean animate) {
        final View drawerView = findDrawerWithGravity(gravity);
        if (drawerView == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No drawer view found with gravity "
                    + gravityToString(gravity));
        }
        closeDrawer(drawerView, animate);
    }
```

also see isDrawerView

```
boolean isDrawerView(View child) {
        final int gravity = ((LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams()).gravity;
        final int absGravity = GravityCompat.getAbsoluteGravity(gravity,
                ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection(child));
        if ((absGravity & Gravity.LEFT) != 0) {
            // This child is a left-edge drawer
            return true;
        }
        if ((absGravity & Gravity.RIGHT) != 0) {
            // This child is a right-edge drawer
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```